# oh-my-zsh turned on autopushd? How can I turn it off?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

It appears that I have `autopushd` turned on (I know I *didn't* turn it on) and it is rather annoying because I prefer to pick and choose when to use the directory stack. How can I turn off `autopushd`?

I have looked in `~/.zshrc` and `~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` but couldn't find anything.

I am using oh-my-zsh on Mac OSX Lion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's set in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh`. I would either comment it out there, or unset the options in your `.zshrc` after loading oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have the `dirpersist`plugin from oh-my-zsh loaded or perhaps you are sourcing some kind of `$ZDOTDIR/z.*` at startup. Have a look at the manpage for [startup files](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files).

Just type `unsetopt autopushd` to disable the feature for the current session and `setopt`to verify that it is really unloaded.

To find the source of the problem I would run `zsh -x 2> log`, exit immediately and inspect the context of every *pushd* in the log...

Answer (score 0):

Just run this and logout and log back in

```
echo "unsetopt autopushd">>~$USER/.zshrc
```

This will append the line to the very end of your .zshrc (after the
loading of oh-my-zsh) so that it overrides whatever oh-my-zsh does.

Logging out ends all zsh-sessions so that when you log back in, all new sessions have the option unset. (You could also kill all zsh-sessions in other ways.)